# Getting api access for a youtube account you are managing

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I manage a youtube account but it seem I can not use the youtube analytics api to pull reports. I can go to the youtube analytics sections of the account and pull the reports but I want to do this programmatically using the api. Is there some other step that need to be done to get access to the account I'm managing.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I was just using the sample code provided by google. I put in the youtube channel Id. The error I got back was I do not have access to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Oharr, I'm facing the same issue and wrote [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48324114/youtube-reporting-api-using-service-account).

There's an alternative automated way to get your reports though. If you use BigQuery, you're able to use the 'Transfers' section. That interface actually creates the Jobs and will give you reports periodically. It also allows you to 'backfill' data from the past up to 180 days.

Please refer to [YouTube Channel Transfers](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/youtube-channel-transfer).
You can also get reports for [Content Owners](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/youtube-content-owner-transfer). But the Content Owner transfers wont' work for me since I get 403 responses. Need to figure that out myself...

Answer (score 0):

Yes in order to pull the data via code you need to get an API key/ service key or Oauth credentials please refer [this link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#installed-applications) for more details.