# YouTube Reporting API using Service Account

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, google-cloud-platform, google-client-login

Following Google's documentation you should be able to use the YouTube Reporting API without user authentication by using a Service Account.

Currently I have a very simple sample that should give me a list of available Jobs, could be empty though. But I get a 403 permission denied.

**Request**:

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('service-account-key.json');

$client->addScope(Google_Service_YouTubeReporting::YT_ANALYTICS_MONETARY_READONLY);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_YouTubeReporting::YT_ANALYTICS_READONLY);

$youtube_reporting_service = new \Google_Service_YouTubeReporting($client);

$jobs = $youtube_reporting_service->jobs->listJobs();
```

**Response**:

Google_Service_Exception

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "The caller does not have permission",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "forbidden"
            }
        ],
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}
```

I verified that the following APIs were enabled:

- YouTube Reporting API
- YouTube Data API v3
- YouTube Analytics API
- Google+ API *(Having my doubts on this one if that is really necessary)*

The thing I don't understand is how the relation should be between projects in Google Cloud Platform and the YouTube accounts.

Has this to do with [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts#delegatingauthority)?

Are you then required to have G Suite enabled?

I see a similar question [How to grant access to Youtube Reporting API for a google service account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339956/how-to-grant-access-to-youtube-reporting-api-for-a-google-service-account)
 exists, but that one may be a bit aged since the last response. I hope my samples and additions will shine a new light over this question.

Is there someone with a working sample? May be in other languages. As long as the flow is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, service accounts can be used to impersonate a user account. Making authorized calls is mentioned in [Preparing to make an authorized API call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequestsO).

But to answer the question, [Service Accounts do not work with the YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#service-accounts-do-not-work-with-the-youtube-api):

> Service accounts do not work for YouTube Data API calls because
>   service accounts require an associated YouTube channel, and you cannot
>   associate new or existing channels with service accounts. If you use a
>   service account to call the YouTube Data API, the API server returns
>   an error with the error type set to unauthorized and the reason set to
>   youtubeSignupRequired.