# Youtube reporting API HttpError 403 error

Tags: youtube, youtube-analytics-api

On my google account (not a Primary account), I have created OAuth credentials which have access to CMS and it's Channels. Using this credentials I am able to fetch data from YouTube Analytics API, so here no problem.

However, when I am trying access YouTube Reporting API, I am only getting the list of reports of Content Owners Reports with an addition of onBehalfOfContentOwner=cms._id parameter and the CMS ID.

```
def list_report_types(cms):
 reporting = youtube.reporting()
 request = reporting.reportTypes().list(onBehalfOfContentOwner=cms._id)
 results = youtube.query(request)
 return results.get('reportTypes') 
report_types = list_report_types(cms)
```

Can anyone help me to also get the list of reports of Channels also?

So when I try to schedule a channel_basic_a2 report, it gives me below error

> HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/jobs?alt=json&onBehalfOfContentOwner=cmsid returned "The caller does not have permission">

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible issues:

Are the oauth credentials you are using service account credentials? Service accounts do not work for the Youtube Reporting API. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48324114/youtube-reporting-api-using-service-account) answer.

Also, have you checked your scopes definition?